# Eventually in a set, meaning?

Tags: measure-theory

For a sequence of events $(F_n)$, define $$(F_n \ evt) = \{\omega \in \Omega \ | \ \omega \in F_n \ \text{eventually} \}.$$

First of all, does this definition mean to say "$\omega \in (F_n) \ \text{eventually}"$? Because $F_n$ itself is just a set, which eiter does or does not contain $\omega$, so it should say $(F_n)$ to denote the sequence and not $F_n$ to denote one set, right?

Secondly, what does it even mean? That $\omega$ will lie in one of the events of our sequence at some point? Just once? I.e there exists at least one n for which $\omega \in F_n$?

Or does it mean that there exists a point after which $\omega$ will always lie in the $F$ sets, i.e, there exists n such that for ALL m > n $\omega \in F_m$? If this is true, how is this any different than the "infinitely often"-set, since there are also infinitely many of these $F_m$ sets now?

Answer (score 1):

An element $\omega$ is eventually in the sequence $(F_n)$ when there exists some $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, it holds that $\omega \in F_n$. For example: Given any $\epsilon >0$, it holds that $\epsilon$ is eventually in the sequence of intervals $F_n = (1/n,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

An element $\omega$ is in the sequence $(F_n)$ infinitely often if there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\omega \in F_n$. For example: Given any element $\epsilon > 0$, it holds that $\epsilon$ is in the sequence of intervals
$$
F_n = \begin{cases}
(1/n, 1) & n \text{ is even} \\
(-1, -1/n) & n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
infinitely often, though not eventually.